Symmetry of the rational points on the algebraic surfaces
I am discovering the following algebraic surface.

$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Q-\{0\}}: z-\frac{1}{z}=x-\frac{1}{x}+2(y-\frac{1}{y})\}$.

This is called the Schubert surface (ref: Heron_triangles_with_two_rational_medians). I want to find rational $(x,y)$s such that $(x, y, z_1)\in S$ and $(y, x, z_2)\in S$ for some rational $z_1,z_2$. In other words, I am looking for pairs of points on the projection surface of $S$ on the $x-y$ plane, symmetrical with respect to the straight line $y=x$.
Is there anyone know how to find them, or can anyone give references about symmetries of points on the algebraic surface?
